# Differentiable at a point and invertible implies inverse is differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, derivatives, inverse

If $f:D\to\Bbb C$ is invertible and real (complex) differentiable at $c$ with $f'(c)\ne0$, it is easy to prove that if $f^{-1}$ is continuous at $f(c)$ and defined in a neighborhood of $f(c)$, then it is also real (complex) differentiable at $f(c)$ with derivative $1/f'(c)$:

$$\lim_{x\to f(c)}\frac{f^{-1}(x)-f^{-1}(f(c))}{x-f(c)}=\lim_{x\to f(c)}\frac{f^{-1}(x)-c}{f(f^{-1}(x))-f(c)}=\frac1{f'(c)},$$

where the latter limit goes to $1/f'(c)$ because $f^{-1}(x)\to c$ as $x\to f(c)$ by the assumption of continuity.

My question is: What additional assumptions are necessary to also deduce the extra assumptions on $f^{-1}$? In the real case, I know that it is sufficient that $f$ be continuous in a neighborhood of $c$, because then $f$ is monotone on an interval around $c$ and $f^{-1}$ is monotone and continuous in an interval around $f(c)$. In the complex case is this assumption sufficient?

Comment: You might want to use or note the fact that if $f:X \to Y$ is a continuous injection with $X$ (Hausdorff and) compact, then $f^{-1} : f(X) \to X$ is also continuous.

Comment: If $f $ is continuous in some neighborhood of $c$ and $f'(c) \neq 0$ then *it does not necessarily imply* that $f$ is monotone in some neighborhood of $c$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh That's true, but what I didn't mention in that paragraph and am assuming for the whole post is that $f$ is also invertible, and over $\Bbb R$ it is true that a continuous invertible function is monotone.

Answer (score 1):

In general on a topological space, a function is invertible iff f is a bijection. A real valued function is a bijection iff it's monotone increasing or decreasing on a closed interval.  It's proven in real analysis that if f is a monotonic function defined on an interval I, then f is differentiable almost everywhere on I i.e. f is nondifferentiable at at most a countably infinite number of points in the interval. (Monotonicity is actually a weaker condition then monotone increasing/decreasing as it requires only the function is nonincreasing/nondecreasing on the interval. However, the function isn't a bijection and therefore, doesn't necessarily have an inverse, if this condition isn't met.)  Obviously, monotonicity isn't an option with complex valued functions since the complex plane isn't ordered.

In fact, for real valued functions,the result you're looking for is this one and you'll see the conditions for a real valued map is considerably stronger then for analytic functions in the complex plane :

[image]

Does that answer your question?

Comment: (1) By invertible I mean an injection, so that $f^{-1}$ is defined on the range of $f$ (which may not be all of $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$). (2) It is not true that a monotone function must be differentiable at all but a finite number of points in $I$, for example $f(x)=1/\lfloor 1/x\rfloor$ (defined on $[0,1]$ with value $0$ at $0$), but it's probably at most countable. (3) I'm already aware of the theorem you've quoted, I mention it at the end of the OP.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro The result actually says that the set of all points of non-differentiability for a monotonic continuous function has Lebesgue measure zero. So that was clearly an error on my part as that implies the set may be countably infinite. I've fixed the statement of the theorem above.

Comment: Ah, okay, and the Cantor function is a counterexample for the claim that it is countable as well - Lebesgue measure zero can actually be quite large in other senses of the word.

Comment: Yes,but the statement says it is differentiable ALMOST EVERYWHERE-which means that the number of points for a local phenomena is "limited" from the standpoint of measure and therefore limits.I doubt any function defined on the Cantor set can be non-zero differentiable at any point.(Yes,I know about the Cantor function. )

Comment: No.... there are bijective functions which are not monotone.....if u add continuity then ok